# ext js 4.2 grid infinite scroll with Ext.selection.CheckboxModel

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I want to make a grid with infinite scroll and Ext.selection.CheckboxModel column.

I need a button 'Select all' but Ext.selection.CheckboxModel does not support this option with infinite scroll.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.selection.CheckboxModel
"pruneRemoved" options .

Could you please suggest any workaround